# How to use jackson + jaxb + xmladapter to serialize to java data type instead of string

Tags: jaxb, jackson, xmladapter

I am using jackson 2.4 + JaxbAnnotationModule

In some cases, I would like to apply an XMLJavaTypeAdapter to the jaxb object, for example the below:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(IntegerAdapter.class)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "int")
protected Integer favoriteNumber;
```

This is working well for the deserialization process. However, it seems that if I serialize the object containing this field to json, the result becomes a string instead of an integer

```
"favoriteNumber": "21"
```

Is there a way to serialize this value to an integer in json with jackson/jaxb while using an XmlJavaTypeAdapter?

Comment: Can you post a complete runnable example that demonstrates the problem. I can reproduce the problem. It works fine for me _without_ using any adapters

Comment: @peeskillet - it serializes to an integer for me too without the adapter.  However, i would like to use the same field "favoriteNumber" for request and response, and when it is used for a request, I would like to use an adapter for additional processing.  Is there a way to have the value serialized as integer while using the adapter?

Comment: did you tried this http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/xml/jaxb/xml-adapter.html?

Comment: I've experienced same problem here... Did you manage to find a solution?